# How to Unit Test a controller that dependends on HttpContext

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I want to know how to unit test my controller when it inherits from a base controller that is dependent on `HttpContext`.  Below is my inherited controller called **BaseInterimController**.  And below that is the `AccountController` method that I wish to Unit Test.  We are using MOQ.

```
public abstract class BaseInterimController : Controller
{

    #region Properties
    protected string InterimName
    {
        get { return MultiInterim.GetInterimName(InterimIdentifier); }
    }

    internal virtual string InterimIdentifier
    {
        get { return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["InterimIdentifier"].ToString(); }
    }
}

public class AccountController : BaseInterimController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [Route(@"{InterimIdentifier:regex([a-z]{7}\d{4})}/Account/Signin")]
    public ActionResult Signin(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var identity = Authentication.SignIn(model.Username,
                model.Password) as LegIdentity;

            if (identity != null && identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // Sign in failed
                ModelState.AddModelError("",
                    Authentication.ExternalSignInFailedMessage);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coupling your controller to `HttpContext` can make your code very difficult to test because during unit tests `HttpContext` is null unless you try to mock it; which you shouldn't really do. Don't mock code you don't own.

Instead try abstracting the functionality you want to get from `HttpContext` into something you have control over.

this is just an example. You can try to make it even more generic if needed. I will focus on your specific scenario.

You are calling this directly in your controller

```cs
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request
    .RequestContext.RouteData.Values["InterimIdentifier"].ToString();
```

When what you are really after is the ability to get that `InterimIdentifier` value. Something like

```cs
public interface IInterimIdentityProvider {
       string InterimIdentifier { get; }
}

public class ConcreteInterimIdentityProvider : IInterimIdentityProvider {
    public virtual string InterimIdentifier {
        get { return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["InterimIdentifier"].ToString(); }
    }
}
```

which can later be implemented in a concrete class and injected into your controller provided you are using Dependency Injection.

Your base controller will then look like

```cs
public abstract class BaseInterimController : Controller {
    protected IInterimIdentityProvider identifier;
    public BaseInterimController(IInterimIdentityProvider identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    protected string InterimName {
        get { return MultiInterim.GetInterimName(identifier.InterimIdentifier); }
    }

    //This can be refactored to the code above or use what you had before
    //internal virtual string InterimIdentifier {
    //    get { return identifier.InterimIdentifier; }
    //}
}    

public class AccountController : BaseInterimController
{
    public AccountController(IInterimIdentityProvider identifier) 
        : base(identifier){ }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [Route(@"{InterimIdentifier:regex([a-z]{7}\d{4})}/Account/Signin")]
    public ActionResult Signin(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var identity = Authentication.SignIn(model.Username,
                model.Password) as LegIdentity;

            if (identity != null && identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // Sign in failed
                ModelState.AddModelError("",
                    Authentication.ExternalSignInFailedMessage);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

This allows implemented controllers to not be dependent on `HttpContext` which will allow for better unit testing as you can easily mock/fake `IInterimIdentityProvider` interface using Moq to return what you want during tests.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Account_Controller_Should_Signin() {
    //Arrange
    var mock = new Mock<IInterimIdentityProvider>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.InterimIdentifier).Returns("My identifier string");
    var controller = new AccountController(mock.Object);
    var model = new LoginViewModel() {
        Username = "TestUser",
        Password = ""TestPassword
    };
    //Act
    var actionResult = controller.Signin(model);
    //Assert
    //...assert your expected results
}
```